pgAdmin ERD relation lines going crazy, is there a way to recalculate?
When I move tables around on pgAdmin's ERD editor the relation lines become all tangled. Is there a way to recalculate the lines? Without deleting them and adding them again manually? Please see the attached image.

I didn't find an option in the main menu to recalculate the lines. Tried moving tables around, right click everywhere to find options to re-calculate the lines...

I agree - being unable to lay out the tables and just say "fix the damn lines" makes this feature pretty much unusable

Sometimes moving a table around can solve. Trying to manipulate the lines dragging then directly made the things worse for me.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Just Drag the lines to far from the tables It will settle and then place it on your desired place,
If didn't understand just ping I will compose a video to demonstrate.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

What worked for me was placing the tables in the desired spot and the click in it Constraints>Foreign key and update the names, then after saving the lines are  kind of better
